# How to reshape data for a stacked barchart using R lattice

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart, reshape, lattice

I have a bunch of data in a table (imported from csv) in the following format:

```
date        classes         score
9/1/11       french          34
9/1/11       english         34
9/1/11       french          34
9/1/11       spanish         34
9/2/11       french          34
9/2/11       english         34
9/3/11       spanish         34
9/3/11       spanish         34
9/5/11       spanish         34
9/5/11       english         34
9/5/11       french          34
9/5/11       english         34
```

Ignore the score column, it's not important.

I need a tally of the total number of students taking English or Spanish or french class based on date, ie. I need to first group it by date and then divide each day into further blocks based on language and plot it as a stacked bar chart so it looks like the following.  Each bar represents a date and each cross section of a bar represents a single language.

I've figured out how to do this once I get the data in a matrix form where each row represents a date and every column an attribute (or language). So I assuming the data is in that form in a csv:

```
ie           french      english       spanish
9/1/11       2           1             1
9/2/11       1           1             0          
9/3/11       0           0             2
9/5/11       1           2             1
```

then I can do:

```
directory<-"C:\\test\\language.csv"
ourdata6<-read.csv(directory)

language<-as.matrix(ourdata6)

barchart(prop.table(language), horizontal=FALSE, auto.key = list(space='right',cex=.5,border=T,points=F, lines=F,lwd=5,text=c('french','spanish','enligsh'),cex=.6), main = list(label="Distribution of classes 10",cex=2.5),  ylab = list(", cex=1.7),xlab.top=list("testing",cex=1.2))
```

The challenge is to get the data from the original format into the format I need.

I tried

```
a<-count(language, c("date", "classes"))
```

where it gives me the counts sorted by both but its in a vertical form

```
ie
9/1/11       french           2             
9/1/11       english          1                       
9/1/11       spanish          1            
etc...
```

I need to pivot this so it becomes a single row per date.  Also if some of these might be zero so I need placeholders for them ie. the first column must correspond to french, the second must correspond to english for my current setup to work.

Any ideas on how to do this or if my approach with matrix + prop.table is even correct? Are there any simpler ways of doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Supposing your data is in a dataframe called `df`, you can do that with the help of the `dplyr` and `tidyr` packages:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

wide <- df %>% select(date,classes) %>%
  group_by(date,classes) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%            # as @akrun said, you can also use tally()
  spread(classes, n, fill=0)
```

Using the example data you provided, this results in the following dataframe:

```
  date english french spanish
9/1/11       1      2       1
9/2/11       1      1       0
9/3/11       0      0       2
9/5/11       2      1       1
```

Now you can make a `lattice` plot with:

```
barchart(date ~ english + french + spanish, data=wide, stack = TRUE,
         main = list(label="Distribution of language classes",cex=1.6),
         xlab = list("Number of classes", cex=1.1),
         ylab = list("Date", cex=1.1),
         auto.key = list(space='right',cex=1.2,text=c('Enligsh','French','Spanish')))
```

which gives the following plot:
[image]

---

EDIT: Instead of using lattice-plots, you can also use `ggplot2`, which is (at least in my opinion) easier to understand. An example:

```
# convert the wide dataframe to a long one
long <- wide %>% gather(class, n, -date)

# load ggplot2
library(ggplot2)

# create the plot
ggplot(long, aes(date, n, fill=class)) +
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position="stack") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.title=element_blank(), axis.text=element_text(size=12))
```

which gives:
[image]

Comment: +1, or `df %>% group_by(date, classes) %>% tally() %>% spread(classes, n, fill=0)`

Comment: @akrun Thanx for pointing to the `tally` function. Learned again something new today :-)

Comment: Hi thanks, where is table name in that command

Comment: @curfewed in which command? Without specifying, it's hard to answer that for me ...

Comment: HI jaap in reality I have tons of columns so specifying spanish + french + english +.. is not efficient.  That's why I tried the prop.table approach.  Your wide is working perfectly, now prop.table(wide) doesn't work unless wide is a matrix, I did wide2<-as.matrix(wide) but now all the numbers have " " around them.  any idea?

Comment: so after wide, I did barchart(prop.table(wide), horizontal=FALSE, auto.key = list(space='right',cex=.5,border=T,points=F, lines=F,lwd=5,text=c('french','spanish','enligsh'),cex=.6), main = list(label="Distribution of classes 10",cex=2.5),  ylab = list(", cex=1.7),xlab.top=list("testing",cex=1.2))   and it's complaing Error in FUN(X[[1L]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

Comment: @curfewed in that case it's probably better/easier to use `ggplot2`, I added an example to my answer

Comment: Hi jaap it is otherwise perfect except for the date issue, order of the date right now is by month end, so first row is 9/1/11, second row is 9/1/2012, third is 9/1/2013, then 10/1/11, 10/1/2012, 10/1/2013, ... I need 9/1/2011, 9/2/2011, 9/3/2011..sequentially.  any idea

Comment: @curfewed as you have an answer to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25975783/reshaped-date-from-month-end-to-chronological) now, is this also solved?

Answer (score 4):

I hope I'm not missing anything, but it looks to me like you're just looking for `table`:

```
table(df[c("date", "classes")])
#         classes
# date     english french spanish
#   9/1/11       1      2       1
#   9/2/11       1      1       0
#   9/3/11       0      0       2
#   9/5/11       2      1       1
```

The result is a `table` (which is also a `matrix`) so you can use your `barchart` command as you wish.

Here's what I get--looks like you need to work on your legend :-)

[image]

The code used was:

```
language <- table(df[c("date", "classes")])

barchart(prop.table(language), 
         horizontal = FALSE, 
         auto.key = list(space = 'right',
                         cex = .5, border = T, points = F, 
                         lines = F, lwd = 5, 
                         text = c('french','spanish','enligsh'),
                         cex = .6), 
         main = list(label = "Distribution of classes 10", cex = 2.5),
         ylab = list("", cex = 1.7), 
         xlab.top = list("testing", cex = 1.2))
```

Comment: thanks this works but the only problem is the order of the date  right now it's order by month end, so first row is 9/1/11, second row is 9/1/2012, third is 9/1/2013 etc

Comment: @curfewed, well, it would help if you used actual dates instead of strings, or if you were using strings, make them ordered factors. Those are irrelevant to your question, which was about how to reshape your data for use with lattice.