# reshaped date from month end to chronological

Tags: r, datetime

I have some data like

```
Date                           col A         col B         col C .......
 01/31/2008 00:00:00.000         
 01/31/2009 00:00:00.000 
 01/31/2010 00:00:00.000               bunch of data
 01/31/2011 00:00:00.000 
 01/31/2012 00:00:00.000 
 01/31/2013 00:00:00.000 
 02/28/2008 00:00:00.000 
 02/28/2009 00:00:00.000               in these columns
 02/28/2010 00:00:00.000 
 02/28/2011 00:00:00.000 
 02/28/2012 00:00:00.000 
 02/28/2011 00:00:00.000 
 03/31/2008 00:00:00.000 
 03/31/2009 00:00:00.000 
 03/31/2010 00:00:00.000 
 03/31/2011 00:00:00.000
 03/31/2012 00:00:00.000 
 03/31/2013 00:00:00.000
 .
 .
 .
```

I need them rearranged so that it looks likes

```
 Date                           col A         col B         col C .......
 01/31/2008 00:00:00.000         
 02/28/2008 00:00:00.000 
 03/31/2008 00:00:00.000               corresponding data
 04/30/2008 00:00:00.000 
 05/31/2008 00:00:00.000 
 .
 .
 .
```

ie right now its month end, I just need them in sequential order any idea how to do this, you can assume there are 6 per date and 12 dates from jan to dec.  Thanks.

Comment: As always: A reproducible example would be nice, or at the very least some data set we can help you with.

Comment: its just a dataframe or matrix or imported file, call it data2.  why would you downvote this

Comment: You might have gotten downvoted, because anyone willing to help has to put in extra effort to do so.

Comment: what extra effort are you referring to, how else would i phrase this question, what else is needed.

Comment: You could `dput` some data, or give us the results of `head()`.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:

```
df <- df[with(df,order(Date)),]
```

Comment: thanks Jaap ended up with df[order(as.Date(df$Date, format="%m/%d/%Y 00:00:00.000")),,drop=FALSE]