# Making stack bar plot of bacterial abundance

Tags: r, plot, bar-chart

I have a dataframe of relative bacterial abundances for 152 samples (rows.) I would like to plot a stacked bar plot of the overall abundances for each bacteria group across all samples (e.g. Actinovacteria vs. Bacteroidetes vs. Firmicutes etc..) I would like it colour-coded, with a legend for this as well. Can someone please suggest how to this? My issue is I'm not sure how to get the column totals for plotting in R. Thank you.

```
row.names       Actinobacteria  Bacteroidetes   Firmicutes  Fusobacteria    Proteobacteria  Verrucomicrobia Other
1   sample1 0.0084246282    0.41627099  0.55475503  0.000000e+00    7.245180e-04    5.391762e-05    1.977092e-02
2   sample2 0.0168571327    0.13298800  0.80289437  3.560112e-05    4.272135e-03    4.238314e-02    5.696180e-04
3   sample3 0.0020299288    0.53813817  0.42367947  3.311006e-02    7.978327e-04    3.534702e-05    2.209189e-03
```

Comment: [Reshape](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1181060) your data then plot. Here is [an example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25936383/680068) using ggplot

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't clear whether the sample names were the row names in your dataframe, so I simply recreated the data frame putting the sample name in a variable, same as the bacteria names:

```
Sample Actinobacteria Bacteroidetes Firmicutes Fusobacteria Proteobacteria
1 sample1    0.008424628     0.4162710  0.5547550 0.000000e+00   0.0007245180
2 sample2    0.016857133     0.1329880  0.8028944 3.560112e-05   0.0042721350
3 sample3    0.002029929     0.5381382  0.4236795 3.311006e-02   0.0007978327
  Verrucomicrobia       Other
1    5.391762e-05 0.019770920
2    4.238314e-02 0.000569618
3    3.534702e-05 0.002209189
```

To reproduce this dataset you can run the following command:

```
df <- structure(list(Sample = structure(1:3, .Label = c("sample1", 
"sample2", "sample3"), class = "factor"), Actinobacteria = c(0.0084246282, 
0.0168571327, 0.0020299288), Bacteroidetes = c(0.41627099, 0.132988, 
0.53813817), Firmicutes = c(0.55475503, 0.80289437, 0.42367947
), Fusobacteria = c(0, 3.560112e-05, 0.03311006), Proteobacteria = c(0.000724518, 
0.004272135, 0.0007978327), Verrucomicrobia = c(5.391762e-05, 
0.04238314, 3.534702e-05), Other = c(0.01977092, 0.000569618, 
0.002209189)), .Names = c("Sample", "Actinobacteria", "Bacteroidetes", 
"Firmicutes", "Fusobacteria", "Proteobacteria", "Verrucomicrobia", 
"Other"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3"))
```

As @zx8754 suggested, this data frame requires reshaping, i.e., moving from a wide format to a long format. For more info, check this [link](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/) for a few examples.

If the dataframe above is named `df`, the following command will reshape it in long format:

```
library(reshape2)
df_long <- melt(df, id.vars = "Sample", variable.name = "Phyla")
```

From here we can plot using ggplot:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = Sample, y = value, fill = Phyla)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

which gives:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to change it so the legend title says 'Phyla' instead of variable?

Comment: Sure, `variable` is simply the name of the column that holds the bacteria name in `df_long`. If you change the name of that column in the data frame the legend title will change accordingly. Alternatively, you can change it directly in the `melt` procedure. I edited the code to add that.

Comment: Or you may change the actual legend title without doing anything with the data: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Graphs/Legends_%28ggplot2%29/